# Why do some rewrite rules fail while AJP is serving all of my requests to Tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy-ajp

I have a Apache server using mod_proxy_ajp to have Jboss/Tomcat5.5 handling all the requests.  Here is how I configured Apache 2.2.17, and for the most part, it works:

```
# Proxy pass all work to Tomcat, mod_jk 1.2.31
<Location />
    # ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
#  and , to handle the redirect of the root dir
Redirect permanent / https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/myapp
```

Unfortunately, **while ProxyPass is enabled**, I am not able to get any mod_rewrite rules to work except for the ones above.  How do I handle this situation?

I am trying to create a rewrite rule similar to this RedirectMatch rule (which only works  if I turn off ProxyPass):

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?i)myagency   "/myapp?agency=MyAgency%20LA"
```

Also, another wierd thing I found, which may provide insight to my issue, is posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/264524/question-about-the-syntax-of-the-proxypass-directive) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out for myself. AJP protocol works differently than HTTP type rules and so they wouldn't mix.   To solve it, I had to stop redirecting everything to AJP  and instead just redirect the application only using AJP.  Here was the answer:

```
# don't ProxyPass through the "/" dir location,
# since it breaks the mod_rewrite rules
<Location /myapp>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/myapp
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/myapp
</Location>
RewriteEngine On
# rule to redirect from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
# rule to redirect /  to the app context since nothing is served at /
Redirect /  /myapp?name=
# supplemental rules to handle URI shortcuts
RedirectMatch ^/(?i)name1   /myapp?name=NameOne
RedirectMatch ^/(?i)name2   "/myapp?name=Name%20Two"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives to RewriteRule directives instead, using [P] to proxy the request, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule (.*) ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Using the [P] option of mod_rewrite didn't work for me.   The only way it will really proxy for me is by using the ProxyPass rule of mod_proxy_ajp .   I think this makes sense since [P] was made for proxies in general, and not for the special case of AJP, right?

Comment: I'm actually not positive, as I've never applied this to AJP specifically. I know that mod_rewrite actually uses mod_proxy to carry out its proxying. I kinda went out on a limb, and assumed that any functionality added to mod_proxy by mod_proxy_ajp (ie, handling ajp:// URLs) would also be gained by mod_rewrite and it's proxying. I'll do a little more poking around :)

Comment: I edited my question (above) to highlight the difference between http/mod_proxy  vs.   ajp/mod_proxy_ajp .

Answer (score -1):

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/$  /index.html  [L]

# RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}e
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fusioncp
ReWriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) ajp://localhost:18009$1 [P]
```