# Question about the syntax of the ProxyPass directive

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, proxypass

All over the internet I see examples of people using ProxyPass, where the syntax looks something like this:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

But, that doesn't work for me.  In my configuration of Apache 2.2.17 and Tomcat 5.5, if I try to do that, my server won't start and gives no clear error message in the logs that tells me why, BUT if I do it this way (shown below) , it does work .  Why is this??  :

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example would work if you changed `ajp` to `http` as that is the http proxy syntax. The [ajp proxy](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/proxy.html) doesn't take the `/path` parameter like the http proxy does.